# "Be back" or "be back home" in context

Tags: phrase-choice

Tell me please if which one is more natural in the following context: *be back* or *be back home*?

> Person A: What time did you get home from work yesterday?
>
> Person B: I was **back**/**back home** at 7 pm.

If neither sounds particularly idiomatic, what would sound so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either sounds fine.  It would probably sound most idiomatic to match the questioner's *get* verb by replying *"I got back [home] at 7pm"*.